# Firefox 4 fonts are bigger than the rest of the apps in Linux

Tags: fonts, firefox, dpi

I mean the fonts of the app itself, not the web pages rendered

If I change the DPI fonts resolutions (appearence preferences, fonts, details) from 96 dpi to, let's say, 80 the look fine, but obviously the rest of the apps get shrinked...

somehow Firefox interprets the DPI setting differently than the rest of the applications

--

using Ubuntu 10.10 and Firefox 4.0, I tried in a VirtualBox machine with similar configuration and it looks good, maybe it's got something to do with the video driver...

Comment: Are you sure you aren't just zoomed in?  try pressing CTRL+0

Comment: @Matt Jenkins hey matt we both did not read carefully at first i think opensas says that the page fonts are ok but the app font like title bar fonts are bigger then usual.

Answer (score 0):

I think I found the answer...

just copy

~/.mozilla/firefox/ioasquri.default/chrome/userChrome-example.css

as

~/.mozilla/firefox/ioasquri.default/chrome/userChrome.css

and add the following line at the end

```
* { font-size: 9pt !important }
```